# How to kill Spark job with job name on standalone cluster

Tags: apache-spark, sandbox, hdp

How can I kill a Spark job with a job name on standalone cluster? How to list Spark jobs ids on sandbox? Is there any command similar to `yarn application -list`?

Comment: Do you want to do it via the command line? You can connect to the master's port 8080 with a browser...

Comment: got  solved. Through shell

Comment: So answer your own question and get credit for it ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
variable=$1
jar=$2
ps -ef | grep -w ${variable} | grep -w 'org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit' | grep -w ${jar}>t.txt
 sed -n 1p t.txt>t1.txt
 awk '{print $3}' t1.txt >kill.txt
 while read x;do
  kill -9 $x
  echo Process Id $x and Application "$variable" killed
done <kill.txt
```